# How to exclude records in excel that have specific attributes

Tags: excel, email, excel-formula, array-formulas

I have a long list of email addresses in an excel sheet where the emails are in column A and I have colors in column B. For instance, see table:

```
   EMAIL                     COLOR
1. test@example.com          red
2. test@example.com          blue
3. testing123@example.com    blue
4. testing123@example.com    blue
5. testtest@example.com      red
6. testtest@example.com      blue
```

I can't figure out how to filter out or remove any email address that is associated with the color red without doing this manually (I have thousands of rows of data, so this isn't happening).

So in this case, the only email address I want to eventually import into my email program is testing123@example.com. Imagine there are thousands of rows like this - is there a conditional formula for column C that can lookup this relationship and provide a "true/false" flag for each email record?

Comment: 2 dimensional array should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. filter by color with criteria red
2. copy all emails affiliated with color red to another column not attached
        to the first 2 columns (put a space between i.e. column F)
3. add a 3rd column and do a vlookup by email =vlookup(a2,F:F,1,0)
4. filter 3 columns by column C everything but #N/A and delete those rows

[image]

Comment: Since I tried this first earlier, it seemed to do the trick. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use an AutoFilter on your color column to display only those rows containing *Red*.  Then delete the visible rows.

See [Contextures](http://www.contextures.com/xlautofilter01.html#FilterCol)

**EDIT#1:**

Based on your comment, we will use a "helper" column.  The "helper" column will mark those rows where either the color is *red* or the email address is duplicated elsewhere with a *red* color.  In the following example, the data is in columns **A** and **B**.  In **C2** we enter:

```
=IF(OR( B10="red",SUMPRODUCT(--(A$2:A$100=A10)*(B$2:B$100="red"))>0),"D","")
```

*(The formula assumes 100 rows of data.)*

[image]

As you see, row#2 is *D* because it is *red* and row#3 is also *D* because row#2 was.

Now set the AutoFilter to display only the *D* rows and delete the visible rows.

Comment: I don't want to keep any rows containing blue if the matching email record exists in a row with red.  Therefore, just simply deleting red rows doesn't accomplish what I set out to do. Make sense?

Comment: So if a row has blue, but has a red "sibling" somewhere else, delete that row as well ??

Comment: @dstep  See my **EDIT#1**